# Why scanner stream is closed

Tags: java, file-io

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class Greencrud {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("greencrud.txt"));
            outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("crudout.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            int a = 0, b = 1;
            int f = 0;
            int total = 0;
            int times = 0;
            int population = inputStream.nextInt();
            int days = inputStream.nextInt();
            int next = days / 5;
            while (times <= next - 2) {
                times++;
                f = a + b;
                a = Math.max(a, b);
                b = f;
            }
            total = f * population;
            outputStream.println("A green crud population starts out as " + population + " pounds of crud");
            outputStream.println("It grows to " + total + " pounds of crud in " + days + " days");
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Input file, `greencrud.txt`:

> 12 10 4 30 28 18 7 13 17 10 9 35 10 20

When I call the method, a problem occurs for `int population = inputStream.nextInt();`. It reminds me that `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed`. Also, I can only output the first line of data in `greencrud.txt` to `crudout.txt`. How can I fix the problem so that all set of dates can be printed on `crudout.txt`?

Comment: you are closing the stream within the while loop.. take it out

Comment: For the input txt file, it is two numbers in a column and totally there are 7 columns.

Comment: I got it! Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are closing stream inside loop

```
outputStream.close();
inputStream.close();
```

Take it out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `inputStream.close();` line outside the `while` loop.

Because the next iteration `inputStream.hasNextLine()` will produce `IllegalStateException` as scanner is already closed.

Same as for `outputStream.close();`.